# Mysql - jdbc connection returning old values even DB contains updated ones

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, tomcat7

i have created a web application using struts, jsp, jdbc, tomcat7 and MySQL. this is mainly fetching data from DB and displaying on UI and based upon user's actions setting some values into the same DB.

this has a UI also for adding , deleting users and listing all users. i am displaying all the users after fetching from the Database. but if a user deletes any user or modifies a  user or creates a user through struts-config.XML after complete processing i am again redirecting user to List of all users. but in that page old user list is displayed although i checked database new values are updated.

after some times either after restarting tomcat server or after few minutes it starts displaying correct data. 
i have tried to set transaction isolation level to READ-COMITTED also but of no use.

kindly help me with that. :(

thanks in advance.